# Notify user if there is something new in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I would like to create something like this in Javascript, and its better if i can do it with Extjs:

[image]

showing a small notification icon on a button when the page contains something new, then when the user click this button and open the page, the icon gone.

It's simple HTML5/JavaScript. I update the web page weekly and would like users to notice the updates.

Comment: Do you Want to get it from remote resource(REST)? Either Ajax synchronization each time interval (to get what is new) or Websockets (established connection, no interval synchro, requires sth on backend to handle websockets, like Node.js and SocketIO).

Comment: Thanks. No not from remote resource. it's simple HTML5/JavaScript. I update the web page weekly and would like users to notice the updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. You have to save a [Cookie](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Cookies) in your browser once the user click the button. If the Cookie is set, then you can hide the notification.

Here an example:

```js
var myCookie = Ext.util.Cookies.get("YourCookieName");
if(!myCookie){
    // show notification
}
```

And on button click:

```js
Ext.util.Cookies.set("YourCookieName", 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. can you show me an example on how to do that please?