# add an icon to a button already has a background image

Tags: javascript, extjs

Using Extjs 4.1, How can I add a red exclamation icon to a button already has a background image? I would like to display this icon to users so they know about new updates in my site. details: [Notify user if there is something new in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728965/notify-user-if-there-is-something-new-in-javascript/16729905#16729905)

Comment: `Ext.getCmp('idOfButton').setIcon('pathToImg')`?

Comment: simple CSS: `.notifying::before { content: "! "; color:red; }`?

Comment: @JeffShaver thanks but this won't work if the button already has a background image

Comment: @Bergi and then how can i remove it when i get the cookie?

Comment: @Oxi: Just add/remove the class on the element